# Access file structure present in host with Docker

Tags: docker, containers

If i want my docker image to directly take data from a folder which is present in my system, is that possible.

If yes then how can I do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you use docker-compose or only docker?

Comment: Docker- compose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual practice is to use **[docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)** (**[bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)**) at runtime.

[image: volume]

```
docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name devtest \
  --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/target,target=/app \
  nginx:latest
```

That way, your container, inside `/app`, has access to your host path (here `$pwd/target`)

In a docker-compose file, see [docker compose volume synta](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes)x:

> This example shows:
>
> - a named volume (`mydata`) being used by the web service,
> - and a **bind mount defined for a single service (first path under `db` service volumes)**.

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: mydata
        target: /data
        volume:
          nocopy: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./static
        target: /opt/app/static

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/postgres/postgres.sock:/var/run/postgres/postgres.sock"
      - "dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"

volumes:
  mydata:
  dbdata:
```

In your case, use:

```
- "/path/to/local/folder/on/host:/path/within/your/container"
```

Comment: So basically the data in "$(pwd)"/target will be used by the docker image , so does docker image copies that data somewhere or just fetches the data at runtime ?

Comment: @adityarawat yes, it is mounted, not copied. You can replace $pwd/target by any path you want from your host. Changes done by the container execution will be reflected in the host.

Comment: Ok, and what is the target here ?

Comment: @adityarawat As I mentioned, "You can replace $pwd/target by any path you want from your host.". And you can mount it to any path you want within your container.

Comment: Okay so that is a path inside the container , thanks

Comment: @adityarawat Sorry, I forgot about the docker compose syntax. I have added a link to the offcial documentation, plus an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you use docker-compose you can define `volumes` to share folders from your system. In example bellow the mysql will use `./data/db/mysql` folder to store/read data (because as default it uses `/var/lib/mysql` in linux).

Also you must to be sure that provided volume has correct permissions and docker have read/write access to it.

```
version: "3"

services:    
    nginx:
        ......

    php:
        ........

    mysql:
        .........
        volumes:
            - "./data/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
```

Comment: docker run -d -it --name devtest --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/target,target=/app nginx:latest,

How do i use mount in compose

Comment: You say that you use docker-compose. In that case you may have different services and each of them may need to use separate mount. So you need to define that mounts inside `volumes` section of `docker-compose.yml` (for each service). And you can build and run your containers just with command `docker-compose up -d --build`.