# Rails assets cache not clearing up - Docker, Rails, Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, nginx

I'm currently using a combination of Rails, Docker, Nginx (Both Rails and Nginx are served as Docker images). I honestly don't know what's wrong in this case. Rails is serving old and non-existent JavaScript and CSS files in production. It's definitely a cache issue. How do I know? I loaded the previous Docker image (which was working) copied and pasted the old URL into the latest image, and they worked! Even if they aren't in the project whatsoever!

I've done some research and haven't found the issue:

This is what I've done:

- Pruned the whole system (`docker system prune -a -p`).
- Pulled the latest Docker images correctly.
- Deleted the `/tmp/cache/assets` folder from Rails
- Used the following commands: `RAILS_ENV='production' rails assets:precompile`, `rails assets:precompile`, `RAILS_ENV='production' rails assets:clean`, `rails assets:clean`, `rails assets:clobber`, `RAILS_ENV='production' rails assets:clobber`
- Deleted manually the `public/assets` folder. And still nothing
- I have even disabled the cache store by doing   `config.assets.cache_store = :null_store`

What do I have:

- Rails 5.1.5
- Nginx 1.13.1
- Docker Compose 3.2

Here's the portion of Nginx that serve the assets:

```
  # We enable gzip as a compression mechanism.
  location ~ ^/(assets|images|javascripts|stylesheets)/   {    
      try_files $uri @rails;     
      access_log off;    
      gzip_static on; 

      # to serve pre-gzipped version     
      expires max;    
      add_header Cache-Control public;     

      add_header Last-Modified "";    
      add_header ETag "";    
      break;  
   }
```

Any ideas? I'm getting error 500 on the new CSS, and JavaScript.

**Edit**:
One more thing. Rails does show the correct URL for the newer assets, but they are hit by a 500 Server error.

**Edit x2 (Added Docker Compose Files)***:
This one is used in development:

```
# WARNING!! Indentation is important! Be careful how you indent.
# All paths that point to the actual disk (not the Docker image) 
# are relative to the location of *this* file! 
# This is the development version of the file. The production one, the
# one that you need to upload is in ./docker-server/docker-compose.yml.
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.3.5
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "rootPassword"
      MYSQL_USER: "ruby"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "userPassword"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "dev"
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql/data
      - ./db/rails_cprint.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/rails_cprint.sql:ro
    networks: 
      - db
  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "4000:80"
    networks:
      - db
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
      LOGSTASH_HOST: localhost
      SECRET_MYSQL_HOST: 'db'
      SECRET_MYSQL_DATABASE: 'dev'
      SECRET_MYSQL_USERNAME: 'ruby'
      SECRET_MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'userPassword'
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3001 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/cprint"
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
      - "1234:1234"
    expose:
      - "3001"
    networks:
      - elk
      - db
  ipmask:
    build: ./reverse_proxy .
    restart: always
    command: "npm run debug"
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
      - "9229:9229"
    volumes:
      - "./reverse_proxy/:/var/www/cprint"
    networks:
      - db
      - elk
    # Only on development!!
    depends_on:
      - db

# Volumes are the recommended storage mechanism of Docker. 
volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: local
  elasticsearch:
    driver: local

networks:
    elk:
      driver: bridge
    db:
      driver: bridge
```

This is the one used in production:

```
# This is the production docker-compose.ymlf ile. 
# This is a docker compose file that will pull from the private
# repo and will use all the images. 
# This will be an equivalent for production.

# The version is super important.
version: '3.2'
services:
  app:
    image: #The private rails URL rails:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: production
      RAILS_PRODUCTION_FULL_DEBUG: 'true'
      RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT: 'true'
    # https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1393
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -e production -p 5000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - /var/www/app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    expose:
      - "5000"
    networks:
      - elk
    links:
      - logstash
  # Uses Nginx as a web server
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652299/having-docker-access-external-files
  # 
  web:
    image: # the private NGINX image URL 
    # Runs it in debug
    # command: [nginx-debug, '-g', 'daemon off;']
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
      - app
      - ipmask
    restart: always
    # Maps the SSL at the same exact location in the server.
    volumes:
      # https://stackoverflow.com/a/48800695/1057052
      # - "/etc/ssl/:/etc/ssl/"
      - type: bind
        source: /etc/ssl/certs
        target: /etc/ssl/certs
      - type: bind
        source: /etc/ssl/private/
        target: /etc/ssl/private
      - type: bind
        source: /etc/nginx/.htpasswd
        target: /etc/nginx/.htpasswd
      - type: bind
        source: /etc/letsencrypt/
        target: /etc/letsencrypt/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - elk
      - nginx
    links:
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
  # Defining the ELK Stack! 
  # If you're moving servers, check the nmap issue.
  # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.3
    restart: always
    container_name: elasticsearch
    networks:
      - elk
    # Default config from elastic.co
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    # Default config from elastic.co
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.2.3
    restart: always
    container_name: logstash
    volumes:
      - ./elk/logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
      - ./elk/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf:/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
    command: logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
    ports:
      - "5228:5228"
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    networks:
      - elk
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.3
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./elk/kibana/config/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
  ipmask:
    image: # the private image URL 
    command: "npm start"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - "NODE_ENV=production"
    expose:
      - "5050"
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
    links:
      - app
    networks:
      - nginx


# # Volumes are the recommended storage mechanism of Docker. 
volumes:
  elasticsearch:
    driver: local
  rails:
    driver: local

networks:
    elk:
      driver: bridge
    nginx:
      driver: bridge
```

Ruby Dockerfile:

```
# Main Dockerfile that contains the Rails application.
# https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/#define-the-project

FROM ruby:2.5.0
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs vim

ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/app

RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT

WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT


COPY Gemfile ./
COPY Gemfile.lock ./

RUN bundle install

COPY . .
```

Note: I have stripped out all sensible information from it.

**Edit x 3** I found the problem. I'm looking into solutions. 
I dug into Nginx's Docker image and I saw Rails' public folder listed. I opened it, and found out that its assets are the old ones. I'll post back once I find the correct solution.

**Edit x 4**
Just the normal Nginx 500 error:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the output of your 500 error you mention?

Comment: @thesecretmasterSure! It's just Nginx plain 500 error page -  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

Comment: I meant the 500 error in the rails logs, but I'm glad you figured it out!

Comment: @thesecretmaster Thank you so much :) and btw, Rails never got hit with a 500 error! I checked the logs and there was nothing (Which was super fishy)... Anyways, Docker volume at fault in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution!

TL;DR

Rails was not the culprit, nor Docker... it was me (Figures ). The problem was that I **manually** copied the public folder when building the Docker image for the Nginx container, but **I never mapped it out** as a shared volume between Rails and Nginx.

## Explanation and solution:

I forgot to post my Nginx Dockerfile. It contained a line that said:

```
# copy over static assets
COPY public public/
```

Which copied Rails' public folder to the Docker image. The caveat was that this ran **only** when I rebuilt the image! Since there were no changes made to Nginx, there was no need to rebuild the image!

The fix was to create a shared volume in the `docker-compose.yml` between Rails and Nginx:

```
# Some lines are omitted 
 app:
    image: rails:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: production
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -e production -p 5000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - public-files:/var/www/app/public
web:
    image: nginx:latest
    # Runs it in debug
    # command: [nginx-debug, '-g', 'daemon off;']
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
      - app
      - ipmask
    restart: always
    # Maps the SSL at the same exact location in the server.
    volumes:
      # https://stackoverflow.com/a/48800695/1057052
      # - "/etc/ssl/:/etc/ssl/"
      # We need to map this so Nginx can read the public files
      - public-files:/var/www/app/public:ro
```