# Docker Service Mount Host Machine Directory Not Work

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I work on a Spring Boot project that connects to remote machine and save files to the machine in a directory. Project work well when running project locally.
The project code related to saving files:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public static final Path ROOT = Paths.get("\\\\IP_ADDRESS\\Upload\\files");
 
private static void saveFileToFileSystem(MultipartFile file, String fileName) throws IOException {
    
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net use \"\\\\"+IP_ADDRESS+"\" "+USER_PASSWORD+" /user:"+USER_NAME);
    
    Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), ROOT.resolve(fileName));

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net use \"\\\\"+IP_ADDRESS+"\" /delete");
}
```

The Dockerfile of the project is below:

```
FROM openjdk:22-slim-bullseye
ADD target/project.name.jar project.name.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/project.name.jar"]
```

I create Docker service to deploy project on the remote machine, namely Docker service host machine as shown below in PowerShell. However, the service cannot access the host machine file system.

```
docker service create --name project-service 
--replicas 2 --publish mode=host,target=8080,published=9100,protocol=tcp  project_image:1.0
```

Then I try to mount the directory with running the code below in PowerShell.

```
docker service create --mount type=volume,source="//e/Upload",destination="/home" --name project-service 
--replicas 2 --publish mode=host,target=8080,published=9100,protocol=tcp  project_image:1.0
```

But I get the error below:

```
invalid mount target, must be an absolute path: /home
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: The code as you've shown it can't really run in Docker: containers can't normally access the host filesystem, and containers can't mount external filesystems.  In a Spring context, I'd also suggest trying to use more portable abstractions around file paths and avoid hard-coding Windows-specific commands like `net use`.

Comment: @David Maze Thanks for your comment. I googled around access from Docker container to host file system, I found out that volume can be applied such as in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800570/access-file-structure-present-in-host-with-docker. Could you explain your statement -"containers can't normally access the host filesystem". I cannot figured out the difference between your statement and the link I provided. Do I miss something?

Comment: The user that starts the container has to give the container special access and permission to do that.  The filesystem paths could be completely different; if it's a Linux container (an `openjdk` image probably is) the DOS-style backslashed paths won't work, and the current directory inside the container isn't necessarily the mounted host directory.